# Determine how much was written to a ChannelBuffer Netty

Tags: netty

I'm using a DynamicChannelBuffer, I'm doing some outputting inside this buffer and I would like how many bytes were written.

How should I get this information ?

Many thanks, Radu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at these methods:

```
writerIndex()
readableBytes()
markWriterIndex()
```

Most likely `readableBytes()` will give you the answer but that depends on what you do with your buffer.

Comment: Done ! writerIndex did the job